# How to use ASP.NET tag in a server control?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I have a dropdown

```
 <div>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="RegistrationDropDownList" runat="server">
         <asp:ListItem Value="NULL">All records</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="1">Submitted records</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="0">Non-Submitted records</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
 </div>
```

I want to Show/hide `<asp:ListItem Value="NULL">All records</asp:ListItem>` based on a session variable

So I tried like this

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="RegistrationDropDownList" runat="server">
 <%if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["user_level"]) == 1){ %>
     <asp:ListItem Value="NULL">All records</asp:ListItem>
 <%}%>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">Submitted records</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="0">Non-Submitted records</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

But I got an error

> code blocks are not supported in this context

I understand I cant use code blocks on controls that have the runat="server" but removing it breaks my code behind logic.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you show us the code behind logic?

Comment: It sounds like that conditional should be in the code-behind instead of the control mark-up.  Maybe in `Page_Load` you can check the conditional and remove the `NULL` value item from the `DropDownList`.  (Or the inverse, check the opposite condition to add the `NULL` value.)

Comment: why don't you just build the list in code behind?

Comment: When you add a runat='server' to an HTML control you change the rendering and code blocks aren't supported inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be done in code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack && Convert.ToInt32(Session["user_level"]) == 1)
    {
        RegistrationDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All records", "NULL"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Blah 2 minutes Good job

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem, do you know why it defaults to the second listitem (Submitted records) after loadin

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame that `ListItem` doesn't have a `Visibility` property that you could bind to.  The best solution I can think of is to write a class that extends `DropDownList`; add a method that inserts the "All Records" item before rendering.

```
public class ExtendedList : DropDownList
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["user_level"]) == 1)
        {
            Items.Insert(0, new ListItem { Value = "NULL", Text = "All Records" });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Items.Add will add as the last item, instead use Insert to add it to position 0

Answer (score 0):

Add it in the code behind

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["user_level"]) == 1)
            {
                ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
                newItem.Value = null;
                newItem.Text = "All record";
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(newItem);

            }
```